# References for Renormalization in Classical Field Theory

Tags: resource-recommendations, renormalization, classical-field-theory

Most references for texts on renormalization talk about renormalization for quantum field theories. However, I have read in some places that we can also renormalize classical field theories. So, are there any references which discuss renormalization in classical field theories, such as for scalar and spinor field theories, Yang-Mills theories, and general relativistic Lagrangians?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/158253/20427

Comment: I saw that answer, but unfortunately they did not post any links to references.

Comment: Sure, I agree. I'm just linking it for the sake of relevance :)